# jquery dialog ui height set to auto, dialog not centered (vertically) in viewport

Tags: jquery, dialog

I am bringing a form into a jquery dialog using ajax - everything is fine. However, I want the dialog to be centered when it first loads. It is (vertically and horizontally) if I set a specific height for the dialog but not if I want to use "auto". It's fine on the horizontal, but it appears far too far down the page (relative to its position if I set a specific height). Has anyone else had this problem, and know of a solution?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

jquery ui dialog is centered by default, but you need to render it on existing element in ajax callback:

html:

```
<div id="container" style="display:none;"></div>
```

javascript/jquery:

```
var container = $('#container');
container.load('YOUR_URL',function(){
    container.dialog({ 
        width: 'auto',
        close: function(ev, ui) {
            $(this).dialog('destroy');
        }
    });
})
```